# Who invoke IHost.Run when using Generic Host Builder in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms

I am trying to digest [a Xamarin.Forms app](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/AllExtensions-DI-IoC) (developed by James Montemagno) on which the Generic Host Builder is applied.

The following is the  `Init` method extracted from [this line](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/AllExtensions-DI-IoC/blob/a56ab47bac42d0a69b3091f0890f8b3f4014b80a/AllExtensions/AllExtensions/Startup.cs#L15):

```
public static App Init(Action<HostBuilderContext, IServiceCollection> nativeConfigureServices)
{
    // others are removed for simplicity

    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((c, x) =>
        {
            nativeConfigureServices(c, x);
            ConfigureServices(c, x);
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(l => l.AddConsole(o =>
        {
            o.DisableColors = true;
        }))
        .Build();

    App.ServiceProvider = host.Services;

    return App.ServiceProvider.GetService<App>();
}
```

Note: `Init` have not run the `host` but it will be invoked from [Android project](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/AllExtensions-DI-IoC/blob/master/AllExtensions/AllExtensions.Android/MainActivity.cs) as follows:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // others are removed for simplicity.
    LoadApplication(Startup.Init(ConfigureServices));
}
```

## Question

Now if I compare with Asp.net Core, we know that `IHost.Run()` is invoked in `Program.Main`. The question is:

Who invokes `IHost.Run()` in the Xamarin.Forms app above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the way I understand it, this setup does not make use of actually *running* the host. Instead, it just relies to *building* it to make sure that DI and all the other related services are available and can be used by Xamarin.

Starting a host actually doesn’t do that much with the generic host. It will [mostly just](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/v3.0.0-preview9.19423.4/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L38-L60) start the host lifetime and run hosted services (like the ASP.NET Core application would be).

But in Xamarin, starting the XAML application is something that already works on its own. So it doesn’t need to be “hosted” (although I rather think that we simply cannot have it owned by the host *yet*).

So this setup just makes use of the host environment to enable DI, configuration and logging, instead of using the host capabilities to actually *run* things. This also means that with this setup you probably won’t be able to run other hosted services within the application (unless you manage a way to properly start and stop the host within the `App`).

Comment: Having read [Andrew Lock's article about using DI in a .net core console application](https://andrewlock.net/using-dependency-injection-in-a-net-core-console-application), I think James Montemagno should just use the same approach as Andrew Lock did because both did not need a running host.